# BubbleView, задать атрибуты программно

Tags: java, android

Для стилизации небольшого форума использую [BubbleView](https://github.com/lguipeng/BubbleView). В форуме почти все надо строить программно. Не знаю как для `BubbleViewLinearLayout` задать атрибуты программно. Например:

```
app:bubbleColor="#   "
app:arrowCenter="false"
app:arrowLocation="Center"
```

Если кто пользовался поделитесь опытом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вот смотрите в GitHub автор точно указывает, где смотреть. 
Всё что вам нужно изменить класс `BubbleDrawable` он отвечает за отрисовку, вот в исходниках видно, где можно изменить. Вот метод в котором это происходит:

```
 private void setUp(int left, int right, int top, int bottom){
        if (right < left || bottom < top)
            return;
        RectF rectF = new RectF(left, top, right, bottom);
        bubbleDrawable = new BubbleDrawable.Builder()
                .rect(rectF)
                .arrowLocation(mArrowLocation)
                .bubbleType(BubbleDrawable.BubbleType.COLOR)
                .angle(mAngle)
                .arrowHeight(mArrowHeight)
                .arrowWidth(mArrowWidth)
                .arrowPosition(mArrowPosition)
                .bubbleColor(bubbleColor)
                .arrowCenter(mArrowCenter)
                .build();
}
```